# Search only in titles of posts in Google Reader 

Tags: search, google-reader

Is there any way to search only in titles in Google Reader?

Most searches show results where the match is in the body of the post, but I would like to restrict it only to match if the keywords are in the title of the post.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, not at this time. It's been a complaint since the search feature in Reader was launched back in '07.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Google Reader operator that implements this at this time.  Using the Google Reader API, one can help facilitate a search for intitle only by first performing the search, and then filtering based on title contents. But again, there is nothing directly from the Google Reader web interface that facilitates this.